# Ocaml Abstract Sytnax Tree

Tags: ocaml, abstract-syntax-tree, software-design, ocamlbuild

I have working expression however when I try to evaluate my expressions with my current evaluate function I get following error-- "Error: This pattern matches values of type 'a * 'b but a pattern was expected which matches values of type args". Could you help me how to fix it.

```
type expr = Const of int 
          | Var of string
          | Plus of args
          | Mult of args
          | Minus of args
          | Div of args
              
and args = {arg1:expr; arg2:expr};; 

let rec eval = function
  | Const c -> c
  | Plus (f, g) -> eval f + eval g
  | Minus(f, g) -> eval f - eval g
  | Mult(f, g) -> eval f * eval g
  | Div(f, g) -> eval f / eval g 
;;
```

Comment: Already answered here https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/ocaml-ast-implementation-with-mutually-recursive-functions/6479

Answer (score 1):

Constructors like `Plus` as you have declared it take arguments that are parenthesized. You appear to be using the syntax appropriate to a record type (with curly braces and field names). But there are no record types in your definition of `expr`.

Here is a valid value of type `expr`:

```
Plus (Const 3, Const 8)
```

Your `eval` function doesn't handle the evaluation of variables (the `Var` constructor). This is only a warning, not an error, but it will cause a runtime exception if you try to evaluate something like `Var "abc"`.

You don't say which of these errors you're talking about, but I hope this is helpful nonetheless.

**Update**

As @CraigFe at discuss.ocaml.org pointed out, you have a mismatch between the definition of `expr` and the test case. You could rewrite your definition of `expr` so that the test case works, or you could rewrite the test case so it works with your current definition of `expr`.

To match the test case, you would want a definition like this:

```
type expr2 =
    | Const of int
    | Plus of { arg1 : expr2; arg2: expr2 }
```

Then you can have a value like this:

```
Plus { arg1 = Const 3; arg2 = Const 8 }
```

However, you can't have field names starting with a capital letter in OCaml. This means that `Arg1` and `Arg2` need to be `arg1` and `arg2`. So personally I would suspect that the test case is the part that needs revision.

I don't understand the part about the mutually recursive definitions (though I know what those are of course). Generally speaking I'd say your biggest difficulty is with the problem statement, not your code.

Comment: @mva you have received answer here https://discuss.ocaml.org/t/ocaml-ast-implementation-with-mutually-recursive-functions/6479

Comment: here I implemented it again according to your suggestion as following   type expr  =
  | Const of int 
  | Plus   of  (arg1: expr ; arg2: expr )  (* e1 + e2 *)
  | Minus of (arg1: expr ;arg2: expr )                 and also changed the test case as following Plus { arg1 = (Mult {arg1 = Const 2; arg2 = Var "x"});
       arg2 = (Mult {arg1 = Const 3; arg2 = (Minus {arg1 = Var "y"; arg2 =Const 1})})
     };;      but got a syntax error due to ';' between arguments

Comment: The code you give here is wrong because it uses parentheses rather than curly braces. However it's not really possible to read code here in comments. You might update your original question if you really are having trouble. But you should be willing to work through a few syntax errors on your own :-)